# Win SSPI Negotiate auth when running a service and client both locally

Tags: java, c#, ntlm, sspi, negotiate

At my job I faced an issue while running a **WebService** locally and doing authentication into it also locally. **WebService** uses **Waffle** with **SSPI** through **JNA** and expects **Negotiate** mech to be used for auth and from the client side I use **Java's** **HttpClient (Apache)** with configured to use **WindowsNegotiateScheme** which uses **SSPI** through **JNA**. While doing **Wireshark** I found that under **Negotiate** **NTLM** is being used and second call on the client side into **InitializeSecurityContext** returns an invalid token which cannot be parsed by **Wireshark** and is said to be invalid by the **WebService** with an error **SEC_INVALID_TOKEN**, but the call to **InitializeSecurityContext** returned **SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED**.

First thing I've tried is to use our client written in **C#** to do the same thing and it succeeds. The second token returned from the client in **Wireshark** is valid and is accepted by the **WebService** to the auth continues and succeeds. In **C#** client we are using **WebClient** with default creds.

Second thing I've tried to generate manually the token interacting directly with **Secur32** lib from a **C++** test app, but I've just reproduced the error. So by this I would say **JNA** is not the issue.

I've also tried different **ISC_REQ flags** while calling **InitializeSecurityContext**, but nothing helped.